# Convergence to half Euler's constant

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Euler's constant is defined by $$\gamma=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac1n-\log N.$$

So we can write it as $$1+\dfrac12+\dfrac13+\ldots+\dfrac1n-\log n\rightarrow \gamma.$$

How can we show that $$1+\dfrac13+\dfrac15+\ldots+\dfrac{1}{2n-1}-\dfrac12\log n\rightarrow\dfrac{\gamma}{2}+\log 2?$$

The fractions are similar, but when they skip the even terms, it's not clear how to relate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding and substracting the inverses of even integers, one sees that the sequence whose limit you are asking is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}-\frac12\log n=(H_{2n}-\log(2n))-\frac12(H_n-\log n)+\log2,
$$
where $H_k$ is the $k$th harmonic number and where we used the fact that $\log(2n)=\log n+\log2$. Since $H_k-\log k\to\gamma$ when $k\to\infty$, this converges to
$$
\gamma-\frac12\gamma+\log2=\frac12\gamma+\log2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the result you quote, we can conclude that

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdots +\frac{1}{n} -\log n \right) \rightarrow \frac{\gamma}{2}$$

Subtracting this from the limit of $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{2n}-\log 2n$ gives the desired result.

Comment: "Subtracting this from the limit of 1+12+⋯+1n−logn gives the desired result" Actually it does not. Upvoter: why the upvote?